# The change of the color in js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, button, colors

I want color of the button to change as it is clicked. But current code doesn't work. It is being applyied but when I click another button nothing happends. Is there better way to do this?

```js
const choices = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("choice-text"));
choices.forEach((choice) => {
  choice.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (!acceptingAnswers) return;

    // Remove the 'selected' class from all of the choices
    choices.forEach((choice) => {
      choice.parentElement.classList.remove("selected");
    });

    // Add the 'selected' class to the clicked choice
    const selectedChoice = e.target.parentElement;
    selectedChoice.classList.add("selected");

  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
      <h2 id="question">What is the answer to this questions?</h2>
      <div class="choice-container">
        <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
        <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">Choice 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="choice-container">
        <p class="choice-prefix">B</p>
        <p class="choice-text" data-number="2">Choice 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="choice-container">
        <p class="choice-prefix">C</p>
        <p class="choice-text" data-number="3">Choice 3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="choice-container">
        <p class="choice-prefix">D</p>
        <p class="choice-text" data-number="4">Choice 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btnNav">
      <button class="btn" onclick="navBack(event)">Back</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="navForward(event)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="game.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please update your code with a working [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Where is `acceptingAnswers` from?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked:

```
choices.forEach((choice) => {
  choice.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // Remove the 'selected' class from all of the choices
    choices.forEach((choice) => {
      choice.parentElement.classList.remove("selected");
    });

    // Add the 'selected' class to the clicked choice
    const selectedChoice = e.target;
    selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add("selected");

    const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset["number"];
    currentQuestion.userAns = selectedAnswer;
  });
});
```

But it stays when I go to the next question.